# In-App Update appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult Android Java

Tags: java, android, in-app

The appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult portion of the In-App Update shown on developer.android shows as being deprecated in Android Studio. I've searched for something that would work in its place, but the most current examples are only in Kotlin, and I'm still using Java... for the time being. Anyway, I understand the appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult that still works has different arguments. I figured out part of it, but still have one error on "Activity".

I tried "MainActivity.this", and I tried just plain "activity",
but it didn't like either of those. The Context Actions suggest "Introduce Local Variable".
I did that... Activity activity; and ActivityResultLauncher activity;
But even though "activity" isn't in Red font color anymore, it's underlined like it's still an issue.

I saw on another post here that [Beyka/Android-TifBitmapFactory](https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory) was a breeze, and [code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid](https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid) but I haven't figured either of them out! Still looking for documentation, and maybe an example... just  to display a TIF

`appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    MainActivity.this,
                    AppUpdateOptions.defaultOptions(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)`